# capistrano-rbenv: Why is it ignoring rbenv_ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, rbenv

OK. So I'm trying to deploy a new version of an app using capistrano. I'm using rbenv, and have 1.8.7 installed (for the old app) and 2.4.1 installed (for the new app). My Capfile includes:

```
require "capistrano/rbenv"
```

and my deploy.rb:

```
set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, "2.4.1"

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Show ruby version"
  task :ruby_version do
    on roles(:all) do |h|
      execute "ruby --version"
      execute "rbenv versions"
    end
  end
end
```

Running `cap production deploy:ruby_version` yields:

```
00:00 deploy:ruby_version
      01 ruby --version
      01 ruby 1.8.7 (2012-06-29 patchlevel 370) [x86_64-linux]
    ✔ 01 deploy@example.com 0.390s
      02 rbenv versions
      02   system
      02 * 1.8.7-p370 (set by /home/deploy/.rbenv/version)
      02   2.4.1
    ✔ 02 deploy@example.com 0.371s
```

I've tried a variety of things — `set :default_env, {"RBENV_VERSION => "2.4.1"}`, removing `/home/deploy/.rbenv/version` (which makes me use `system` ruby) — but nothing seems to let rbenv_ruby override the other setting.

Setting `rbenv_ruby` to a nonexistent version throws an error, so it appears to be doing *something.*

I'm going nuts. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to use `~/.ruby-version` file with `2.4.1` ?

Comment: Yes, that gives me 2.4.1. I still want to be able to set the version in my deploy.rb file, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. Instead of

```
execute "rbenv versions"
```

I wanted:

```
execute :rbenv, "versions"
```

the two look real similar but are not at all the same:

http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/tasks/

> tl;dr: execute(:bundle, :install) and execute('bundle install') don’t behave identically!

siiiiiiiiiiiiiiigh